# Math Skills Game Advice

Tags: javascript, game

I think my code works pretty well, although I'm biased: http://jsfiddle.net/AHKb4/2/

***Basic Overview:** I'm working on building a math skill game, where the objective is to drag and drop div's to a container. Each div will have a value, likely set with classes. Each container must equal `theSumNum` to pass the level. Just giving this info so you can possibly understand better what I'm trying to achieve.*

1. Most importantly I think I've got my main function `pickNumbers()` ready to go. But I'd really appreciate any opinions and advice that you have for that function.
2. I've made two classes so far, `three` and `five`. I'm planning though to have classes from two through ten. I'm thinking each class will have an amount of arrays equal to that class number. Likewise there will be x number of container divs for x number of arrays.

   So I think I could obviously improve how I do my classes by creating a for loop to generate the classes when needed, and use like `myArray1` instead of `myArrayOne`.  I'm just looking for a `True` or `False` answer for this question.
3. Lastly, please take a look at the function `pickFive()`. So again I'm assuming I could just use a for loop for that as well? Just looking for a `True` or `False` here too, but if there's anything to look out for or be careful of in doing it that way, please let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var three = {
    myArrayOne: [],
    myArrayTwo: [],
    myArrayThree: [],
    myArraysCombined: []
}
var five = {
    myArrayOne: [],
    myArrayTwo: [],
    myArrayThree: [],
    myArrayFour: [],
    myArrayFive: [],
    myArraysCombined: []
}
// theArray is the array to push to  ~ ex(three.myArrayTwo)
// theNum is the amount of numbers that will be in the array  ~ ex(3)
// theSumNum is what the sum of all the numbers in the array will equal  ~ ex(20)
// theMaxNum is the largest number that can appear in the array, except the last number may be larger since its not random  ~ ex(10)
// theMinNum is the smallest number that can appear in the array  ~ ex(1)
// aRandNum is a temporary var for each number in the array, except for the last number in the array
// thePreSumNum is the sum of all the numbers in the array except for the last number
// theLastNum is the last number that will be pushed to the array, this number is not random
function pickNumbers(theArray, theNum, theSumNum, theMaxNum, theMinNum) {
    for (var x=0; x < theNum;) {
        var aRandNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*theMaxNum + theMinNum);
        if (theArray.indexOf(aRandNum) === -1) {
            if (theArray.length < (theNum - 1)) {
                theArray.push(aRandNum);
                x += 1;
            }
            if (theArray.length === (theNum -1)) {
                var thePreSumNum = 0;
                for (var e = 0; e < theArray.length; e += 1) { thePreSumNum += theArray[e]; }
                var theLastNum = theSumNum - thePreSumNum;
                    if (theArray.indexOf(theLastNum) > -1 || theLastNum < 1) {
                        theArray.length = 0;
                        x = theNum;
                        pickNumbers(theArray, theNum, theSumNum, theMaxNum, theMinNum);
                    }
                    else {
                        theArray.push(theLastNum);
                        x += 1;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

function pickThree() {
    pickNumbers(three.myArrayOne, 3, 20, 10, 1);
    pickNumbers(three.myArrayTwo, 3, 20, 10, 1);
    pickNumbers(three.myArrayThree, 3, 20, 10, 1);
    three.myArraysCombined = three.myArrayOne.concat(three.myArrayTwo, three.myArrayThree);
}

function pickFive() {
    pickNumbers(five.myArrayOne, 5, 40, 20, 1);
    pickNumbers(five.myArrayTwo, 5, 40, 20, 1);
    pickNumbers(five.myArrayThree, 5, 40, 20, 1);
    pickNumbers(five.myArrayFour, 5, 40, 20, 1);
    pickNumbers(five.myArrayFive, 5, 40, 20, 1);
    five.myArraysCombined = five.myArrayOne.concat(five.myArrayTwo, five.myArrayThree, five.myArrayFour, five.myArrayFive);
}

pickThree();
pickFive();
    
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions I made:

- The `3` object will have 3 arrays, just as the `67` object will have 67 arrays
- The "combined" array can be computed on demand
- Each call to `pickNumbers` for a certain object will always have the same parameters

Firstly for your objects, I think they belong in a namespace and also a way to define which numbers you want to be in the game:

```
var Game = {}
Game.NUMBERS = [3, 5];
```

Next instantiate all the classes:

```
for (var i = Game.NUMBERS.length; i --) {
  Game[Game.NUMBERS[i]] = new GameNumber(Game.NUMBERS[i]);
}
```

Let's define what your class would look like:

```
var GameNumber = function(number) {
  this.number = number;
  this.arrays = [];
  for (var i = number; i --) {
    this.arrays.push([])
  }
}
GameNumber.prototype.combined = function() {
  Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.arrays)
}
GameNumber.prototype.pick = function(arrayLength, sum, max, min) {
  for (var i = this.number; i --) {
    pickNumbers(this.arrays[i], arrayLength, sum, max, min);
  }
}
```

Cool, so now you can create your objects in a sufficiently general way and call `pick` or `combined` on any of them.

```
Game[3].pick(5, 40, 20, 1);
Game[3].combined() // Output: [...]
```

As for the `pickNumbers` function, I didn't look at the logic too heavily, I'm sure that's working how you want it to. The variable names I would simplify to `array`, `arrayLength`, `sum`, `max`, `min` for readability. You may also want to attach it to the `Game` object so you have less globals (ie `Game.pickNumbers = function(...)`). I'd also try and abstract the html from it so as to separate logic from presentation.

Note: I haven't tested this code, it's only to give you an idea of how to structure it.